# @Column is setting column name due to the variable

Tags: java, database, jpa, columndefinition

I have this code:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TrainingData {

    @Column(name = "RECORD_DATE_PARSED")
    private LocalDate recordDate;

    @Column(name = "SENDER_POSTOFFICECODE")
    private String senderPostOfficeCode;
}
```

This is sending to SQL query columns with names: "RECORD_DATE" and "SENDER_POST_OFFICE_CODE"
How can i turn off auto adjust column title based on variable?
And have this error:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "C1_0"."RECORDDATE": ???????????? ?????????????
```

I tried to turn it off using application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

But nothing helped( Because my column names changed to: "RECORDDATE" and "SENDERPOSTOFFICECODE"

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you specify exaclty what name do you expect and what do you actually got?